# Limit Angular UI-Bootstrap Typeahead to specific object property

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have the following [Angular](http://angularjs.org/) [UI-Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) [typeahead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) working great:

```
<input class="span2" type="text" ng-model="selectedStuff" typeahead="stuff as stuff.name for stuff in stuffs | filter:$viewValue"/>
```

Though, it's almost working *too* great. I'm able to display the `stuffs.name` for the purposes of the `typeahead` AND select the full `stuff` object in `stuffs`. The problem is that my `$viewValue` is matching all of the properties in `stuff` instead of just the `stuff.name`. I've tried adding the `.name` to various places in the `typeahead` with no luck. Is there a straightforward way to display and match only the `.name` but still return the entire object?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The typeahead directive from the http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ repo was build to well fit into existing AngularJS ecosystem. This means that this directive tries to re-use as much as possible of syntax, filters and directives already used in AngularJS.

Back to your question - the filtering itself is done by the Angular's filter filter described here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter The mentioned filter's syntax is flexible enough to limit searches to a selected set of properties:

```
typeahead="stuff as stuff.name for stuff in stuffs | filter:{name: $viewValue}"
```

Please notice: `filter:{name: $viewValue}`

Working plunk here: http://plnkr.co/edit/o1qWKq8LSmbbmVaYkOvb?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much! I swear I've been trying to RTFM, but I guess I'm going to have a to keep at it.

Comment: I don't see the difference that `filter: {name: $viewValue }`
I tried changing it to `filter: $viewValue` and the output was the same.

Comment: @SaadFarooq When you change the syntax t `filter: $viewValue`, angular basically creates a JSON string out of the object and searches that.  The syntax pkozlowski used searches ONLY the name field. Test using the word "second" on the Plnkr above.  It appears no where in the name fields.  If you edit it as you've suggested, then "second" would show the 2nd result.